# A "neat" way of getting rid of all but diagonal entries of Hermitian matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose $M$ is an $n\times n$ **Hermitian** matrix. Write $M'$ for the $n\times n$ matrix such that $M'_{ij}=0$ whenever $i\neq j$ and $M'_{ii}=M_{ii}$ for every $i$. To obtain $M'$, we replace every entry of $M$ by $0$ except its diagonal entries. Is there a nice expression for the operation that maps $M$ to $M'$?

Comment: $M'$ is known as the *diagonal part* of $M$ (see discussions of Jacobi's method e.g. [[1](http://www.maa.org/press/periodicals/loci/joma/iterative-methods-for-solving-iaxi-ibi-jacobis-method), [2](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/JacobiMethod.html)]), but I don't think there is a standard notation for it.

Answer (score 0):

It can't get much simpler than what you already said, but how about $$M'=\sum_{i=1}^n (e_i^* M e_i) e_ie_i^*$$
where $e_i$ are the standard basis vectors.

Comment: Nothing like an obscure formula to replace a perfectly clear description of something!

Comment: I don't know, @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez, you're probably right. But it does let us see what's going on without being tied to a specific matrix representation and its matrix elements - we could do this for an arbitrary linear transformation and a set of $k$ L.I. vectors  It all depends what $M'$ is going to be used for.

Comment: $M'=\sum P_i^TMP_i$, where $P_i=e_ie_i^T$.